# Table cell pushed to a next row

Tags: html, css

I am creating a newsletter template with full [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/nGBIa)

I have a few Table rows as follows:

```
<tr>
  <td class="snip" valign="top">
    <table class="snip" style="padding-left: 8px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/40x32" style="padding: 4px">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          THIS IS THE TITLE 1
        </td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
         <span>THIS IS THE LINK 1 FOR TITLE 1</span>
         <br>
         <span>THIS IS THE LINK 2 FOR TITLE 1</span>
         <br>
         <span>YET ANOTHER LINK FOR TITLE 1</span>
         <br>
         <span>ONE MORE LINK FOR TITLE 1</span>
         <br>
         <span>AND THE LAST LINK FOR TITLE 1</span>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Somehow when I resize the browser to a specific width I get:

[image]

You can see that the last TD goes to a next row ...

How can I solve this problem? I can't find the solution ...

Answer (score 1):

look this, I set two different tr with class

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iyEmK

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
      tr.myTR {float:none;display:block;clear:both} }
```

Comment: This also does not work ... There is a moment where the columns are not vertically aligm, e.g., the two columns on the right are not horizontally aligned ...

Answer (score 1):

Use `min-width` instead of `width`

```
table[class="snip"] {    
    min-width: 50% !important;    
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzGKo

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
td[class="snip"]:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

so that the narrow screens have rows of two elements.

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/lbxEe

Comment: I am using this for a newsletter ... Should I use nth-child?

Comment: not sure you should be using media queries then ! But to avoid the `nth-child` you could add a class to every second td and apply the `clear:left` through that class.

Comment: yes good point ... I started to follow a template and they use media so I though it was safe: http://internations.github.io/antwort/